# Swagger codegen with write_only PrimaryKeyRelatedField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

In our project we have the following case more than once:

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    unit = UnitSerializer(read_only=True)
    unit_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Unit.objects.all(), source="unit", write_only=True)
```

This is according to our best practices where variables should describe which type they contain. In `drf-yasg` this is shown however as required in both the Read and the Write way. This means that code generators will mark this field as required, and when our API response comes in, they invalidate the request, because the `unit_id` is missing. Is there a way to declare this field as `write_only` other than this parameter?

[image: Swagger UI of the problem]